# Custom Operator Precedence Issue in Swift?

Tags: swift, operator-precedence

I'm trying to implement a custom infix power operator using the "^" character with the following code, but I'm getting unexpected results.

```
precedencegroup PowerPrecedence {
    associativity: right
    lowerThan: BitwiseShiftPrecedence
    higherThan: MultiplicationPrecedence
}

infix operator ^ : PowerPrecedence

func^(lhs:Float,rhs:Float) -> Float {
    return pow(lhs,rhs)
}
```

When I use the ^ operator in the following statement,

```
let x = 1 + 10 ^ Float(2)
```

I expect `x` to be 1 + (10^2) = 101, but `x` is (1+10)^2 = 121 instead. What am I missing?

Comment: I can't repro this: getting 101 in playground

Comment: Tested in console app, cannot reproduce either.

Comment: I also get the correct result using a Mac command line tool.

Comment: Apparently, the issue was resolved between Xcode 11.3 and 12.4.